# execution of the interrupt based on condition

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I have declared an interruption but I want to execute it only when one boolean variable is equal to true.

Other words:

- when boolean value is true -> "listen" for interruption,
- when boolean value is false -> "don't listen" for interruption

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to always let the interrupt execute, and test for the boolean inside the interrupt code? Just slap an `if (myBoolean) {}` around the interrupt code. Easier than attaching/detaching in the loop(), which could also give timing problems.

Comment: Of course there is.  You can use a bool to activate it or not.  Or you can leave it running and only pay attention to it when you want.  You should first read the datasheet for your part and *understand* interrupts.  The crappy and bloated Arduino code libraries shield you from the details you need to know.

Comment: So, where can I find such information how to enable and disable this interruption linstening ?

Comment: show your sketch please

Comment: @niepewnyjutra  The information would be in your microprocessor's programmer's guide.   What you want to do is definitely possible... But since we do not know which processor you're targeting,,nor which interrupt you want to disable, it's very difficult for anyone to give you any more details.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I'm using Arduino Uno platform and I would like to control attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), ISR, mode)

And also I could achieve my goal using millis() but I just wanna know how to do it with interrupt

Comment: you can use detachInterrupt

Answer (score -1):

The concept of an interrupt might be confusing sometimes. In general the interrupt will be executed independently of any variables. You can't define the condition in this way. If you want to control the interrupt you need to enable or disable it.

The real interrupt enable flag can be at several locations depending on the hardware platform. The AVR micro-controller (used on most Arduino devices) gives you two possibilities: source interrupt enable at the peripheral rasing the interrupt request and global interrupt enable.

You should not disable the global interrupt flag except for a very short period of time. This could give you side effects that you wouldn't expect, e.g. serial output to PC. You would probably seeing nothing anymore.

The interrupt enable bits (flags) at the peripherals have individual meanings. So you must lookup the flags in the manual for the specific peripheral. The USART has three interrupts enable flags: RXCIE, TXCIE, and UDRIE for "RX complete", "TX complete", and "USART data register empty". Please look in the manual for details.

Comment: "AVR micro-controller used on most Arduino devices"? please update your KB. and if OP uses Arduino's attachInterrupt then registers are not the right way for them

Comment: @Juraj Where did you read "attachinterrupt" in OP's question? Please re-read the question. OP wants a flag to control interrupt handling.

Comment: I said "if". the question it is tagged [arduino] so the answer should be about Arduino not about AVR